# How to hide the text "REFERENCES" in header?

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref,natbib}
\markboth{}{}
\begin{document}
    \def\bibname{\uppercase{REFERENCES}}
    \def\refname{\uppercase{REFERENCES}}
    \cleardoublepage
    \newpage\phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{Daftar Pustaka}}
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
        \bibitem[Mathews (2004)]{bar} 
        Mathews, J.H. dan Fink, K.D. 2004. \textit{Numerical Methods Using Matlab Fourth Edition}. New Jersey: Prentice-Hall, Inc.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to hide the text "REFERENCES" in header (the page number is still show). I use `\markboth` and it cannot hide the text "REFERENCES". How to hide the text "REFERENCES" in header?

Comment: Use \pagestyle{plain}just before your  bibliography, and any style you please afterwards.

Comment: Type `\markboth{}{}` after `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`.